# How to "Un-Eject" a USB Flash drive -- Eject is easy (safely remove hardware), but what about Un-Eject or Reconnect?

Tags: windows, usb, mount, usb-flash-drive, eject

There are times after I eject a USB Flash drive, I want to copy some more files over to the USB Flash drive.  In this case, do I always need to unplug the drive and plug it back in?  Is there a way to "reconnect" or "un-eject" the drive?

To eject, that are two ways:

1. Right click the drive (say H:) and choose Eject
2. Click "Safely remove hardware" from the icon tool

But there seems to be no way to un-eject or reconnect a drive.

Comment: you're obviously using windows, but this is the same question for OSX: http://superuser.com/questions/110856/how-can-i-remount-an-ejected-not-just-unmounted-usb-drive-on-mac .. related questions on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916296/how-can-i-cycle-a-usb-device-from-c/919836#919836 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138394/how-to-programatically-unplug-replug-an-arbitrary-usb-device

Comment: It's a lot faster to just remove and reinsert the USB plug, rather than clicking twenty times in Windows dialogs. MHO.

Comment: @torbengb: sometimes, it's an internal USB connection that you can't easily replug, so this is faster than rebooting the machine.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun - Sometimes the computer with the USB drive is in a server room in a building very far away.

Comment: @Kenny: I get it y'all :-) quit bashing me for something I said two years ago.

Comment: Or it’s a flash-drive plugged into the back of the computer under the desk. Physical access isn’t always easy/possible. One *could* reboot to have it remounted, but that’s much more annoying than clicking twenty times. That should last for another two years. `:-P`

Comment: Related: [How do I get Windows Vista or Windows 7 to re-attach a USB device without having to plug it in again?](http://superuser.com/questions/32023/how-do-i-get-windows-vista-or-windows-7-to-re-attach-a-usb-device-without-having)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to remount the drive. Depending on the operating system there are several ways to do this.

Assuming Windows:

> 1. Right click My Computer and select Properties (or you can simultaneously
>      press Win+Pause/Break key). In System
>      Properties window, go to the Hardware
>      tab and then click the Device Manager
>      button. In Windows Vista or Windows 7,
>      you can just click the Device Manager
>      link located at the left hand sidebar
>      when you are at the System Properties
>      window.
> 2. Click View from the menu bar and select “Devices by Connection“.
> 3. Find the parent USB Root Hub of the USB device that has a yellow color
>      exclamation mark. Right click on the
>      USB Root Hub and select Disable. Again
>      right click on the same USB Root Hub
>      that you’ve just disabled and this
>      time select Enable.
>
>    [image: Window]

From [Remount Ejected or Safely Removed Drive](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/09/07/remount-ejected-or-safely-removed-usb-device-without-unplug-and-reinsert/).

A little Google-Fo will yield results for [OS X](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=iFU&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=remount+usb+drive+mac&aq=f&aqi=g-sx1g-msx1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and [various Linux distro's](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=4uo&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=remount+usb+drive+linux&aq=f&aqi=g-sx6g-msx2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Comment: note that disabling & re-enabling the Root Hub will reset *all devices on that hub* -- it will work, but that could be a nasty side effect under some circumstances.  **if there are other USB drives on that hub, you should eject/unmount them all before performing this procedure.**

Comment: Why is a restart required before this will work? : http://screenshoot.me/JuItNj

Comment: I too get the same dialog box as @Pacerier.

Comment: @HNL exactly, that sorta defeats the purpose

Comment: @Pacerier: Maybe you get the restart required message because you're using Win XP and Josh K isn't.

Answer (score 0):

A reboot is required with Windows 7, simply logging off and back on isn't sufficient.  Given than, what not save time and just reboot without the above procedure?

Comment: See [How do I get Windows Vista or Windows 7 to re-attach a USB device without having to plug it in again?](http://superuser.com/questions/32023/how-do-i-get-windows-vista-or-windows-7-to-re-attach-a-usb-device-without-having)

Comment: a reboot? can't I just pull the USB Flash drive out and plug it back in?

Comment: This answer may be rediculous, but technically is accurate :)